# Parse Variant to TXSDateTime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, variant

I want to parse my result objects from a webservice in Delphi. Now I need to parse a Variant to `TXSDateTime`, because i don't know the Type. For Example:

```
if propInfo.PropType^ = TypeInfo(TXSDateTime) then
begin
    value := GetPropValue(objects[i], propInfo); //only returns a Variant
    dateXSvalue := ???; //need to parse value to dateXSvalue;
end;
```

The function now returns a `Variant` that I can't parse to a `TXSDateTime`. It would work if I know the Type, so for example:

```
dateXSvalue := Contract(objects[i]).StartDate;
```

So how is it possible to parse a Variant to a TXSDateTime without knowing the exact type?

Comment: What does `VarType(value)` give you? It's likely a pointer to the TXDDateTime instance.

Comment: @GolezTrol it Returns 3

Comment: 3 = `varInteger` (unit System, as referenced by the documentation on VarType). Could indeed be a pointer. Could you try `TXSDateTime(Integer(value))` and see what it does for you?

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks a lot! It works this way! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variant will contain an integer (`VarType(value) = varInteger`), which holds the address of the TXSDateTime instance. You should be able to simply cast it like this:

```
XSDateTime := TXSDateTime(Integer(value));
```